# No tag for anime/manga series and not enough reputation to create tag; what tag to use?

Tags: discussion, tags, asking-questions

I have a question about *Buddy Complex* production.

No tag exists for this series yet, but I also do not have the tag creation privilege here.

What tag should I use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently, our suggested workaround for this situation is to **use [retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag) and clearly state the name of the series in your question** (and, if it isn't obvious, the intended tag name).

A user with sufficiently high reputation will edit the proper tag in. This usually happens almost immediately, but if it doesn't within a day or two you can flag for moderator attention requesting the tag to be edited.